# Extract info sent between two Activities in adapter for Android app

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent

My first Activity displays images in a grid and implements onclick method on each image, which will send info and open second activity upon click.

I want to construct an image adapter to manipulate that image in the second activity. How can I extract that image id of the clicked image inside of the image adapter to tell the adapter that I want it to work with the image that was clicked in the first activity?

Code that starts `FullSize` Activity:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){ 
       Intent puzzle = new Intent(this, FullSize.class); 
       puzzle.putExtra("selected_img", id); 
       startActivity(puzzle);
}
```

Comment: by way of an onItemClick, the INTENT carries the ID of the clicked image, which exists in drawable res folder.                                                                                                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){

        Intent puzzle = new Intent(this, FullSize.class);
        puzzle.putExtra("selected_img", id);

        startActivity(puzzle);

Comment: So you will only have one image in your image adapter?

Comment: yes. I will use that adapter to create a bitmap array of sections of the image to display in reverse order onto the gridview of the second activity.

Comment: or maybe theres a better way...

Comment: It looks like you are actually sending the row ID from your first activity, and not the image ID.  See documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html   Do you have a list of Image Resource IDs in the first activity?

Comment: My first activity references and searches for images from my drawables file. I manually placed that list of  images inside of that file.

Comment: Yeah.  So, when you call `puzzle.putExtra("selected_img", id);`, `id` is actually the row ID.  What you need to pass is actually `imageList.get(position)` to get the Image Resource ID for the currently selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass in the image ID to the constructor of the custom adapter.

First of all, make sure you're sending the Image Resource ID.  Currently it looks like you're sending the row ID in the extras.
When you call `puzzle.putExtra("selected_img", id);`, `id` is actually the row ID of the `AdapterView`. [See documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long))

What you need to pass is actually `imageList.get(position)` to get the Image Resource ID for the currently selected item.

Once you get that working, you could do something like this:

Passing in your image ID:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int imageID = i.getIntExtra("selected_img", 0);
ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(this, imageID);
```

Custom adapter, with the image ID as a parameter in the constructor:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        int imageID;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c, int imageResourceID) {
            mContext = c;
            imageID = imageResourceID;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(imageID); //use the image id passed in through the constructor

            return imageView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand and appreciate your help but I am a little confused as to what  "imageList" refers to in the "imageList.get(position)" statement. Please let me know.

Comment: That would be an ArrayList that contains the image resource id's in the first Activity. Basically you need some way to get the image resource Id before you send it through the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between activities using Extras

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imgId", id);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then to get it back in the second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int imgId = intent.getIntExtra("imgId");
```

How you handle the id's is up to you.

Comment: thnnks for the response. I have actually done all of this , but I now want to access that "imgId" with the ADAPTER. How can I do so?

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers your question please select it as the correct answer.

Comment: I have actually done all of this , but I now want to access that "imgId" with the ADAPTER. How can I do so?

Comment: well what exactly is the id? do you want the view's id? you can get that from the onclicklistener with view.getId()

Comment: is it possible to use the same id that was sent through the intent in the adapter ?

Comment: this is how I send the extras:     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
   
        Intent puzzle = new Intent(this, FullSize.class);
        puzzle.putExtra("selected_img", id);
      
        startActivity(puzzle);

Comment: do you have a custom Adapter?

Comment: i have a custom adapter class that is referenced by the second activity with: "secondActivityView.setAdapter(new customAdapter(this))"

Comment: Are you sure its the id you want and not the src?

Comment: how can i let the adapter that I will reference in the second activity know to use the img that was clicked in the first activity ?

Comment: Like I said, with putExtra and getExtra. You don't need to send the "id" you need to either send the path to the image or maybe (wouldn't recommend it) the image data itself.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in earlier answer you could use `putExtra`
Or you can use `setData`. If you are dealing with images outside of your app resources, you'll have to deal with `Uri`s. In this case, use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the second activity you can use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri uri = intent.getData ();
```

the `Uri` object can be used to read the image file or meta data about image. Uri can be of a remote file too.

Comment: thnks for response. The image is NOT outside of the apps resource but within the drawable file. The intent I sent beforehand functions well in sending that INTENT DATA to the second activity. What I am attempting to do is to access that same INTENT DATA within my custom adapter (that is called within second activity) to alter the img that was clicked. Is this possible ?